# expected Number al intentar ir hacia una coordenada

Tags: javascript

**Desarrollo**

Buenas.
Estoy desarrollando todo un sistema de vehículos para un servidor de la API Rage Multiplayer, del juego Grand Theft Auto V, es decir, un servidor de Roleplay.

Estoy trabajando en un sistema de vehículos en el cual una vez creado un vehículo se registra en la base de datos, guardando datos importantes como el modelo, coordenada, color del vehículo, entre otros. Entonces, cuando el propietario de ese vehículo conecte al servidor, la consola realiza una consulta a la base de datos y crea en el juego el objeto del vehículo a base de la información de la DB (como dije antes, modelo, coordenada, color, entre otros).

Todo eso funciona genial, la cosa es que quiero hacer un comando cuya función sea teletransportar al usuario que ejecuta el comando hasta un vehículo específico (cada vehículo tiene una ID en la base de datos, es decir, una columna con valor autoincremental).

Entonces, teniendo en cuenta el objetivo, lo que hice fue lo siguiente;
Cree el comando titulándolo irv, primero que nada el comando revisa que tengas permisos, en este caso es un comando que únicamente podrán usar los administradores, por lo cual, si tus permisos son inferiores al nivel 3 (Moderador 1) no podrás utilizar este comando.

Lo segundo que verifica el comando es que menciones correctamente una ID de vehículo, por ejemplo, queremos ir hacia el vehículo 11, entonces debemos escribir el comando de la siguiente forma;

```
/irv 11
```

Luego añadí un `try` y un `catch` para obtener más información en caso de un error, y seguido de eso coloqué la consulta a la base de datos en una constante llamada `coord`.

```
    const coord = await misc.query(`SELECT coord FROM vehicles WHERE id = ${veh}`);
```

Finalmente, si se encuentra el vehículo número 11 en la base de datos, el sistema te debe llevar hasta su ubicación (x, y, z) y a su dimensión.

```
player.position = new mp.Vector3(coord.x, coord.y, coord.z);
player.dimension = coord.dim;
```

**Código**

A continuación dejo el código completo, para entenderlo mejor.

```
// Teletransportarse a un vehículo.
mp.events.addCommand("irv", async (player, veh) => {

    if (player.adminlvl <= 3) {
        return player.outputChatBox(`!{red}[ERROR]: !{white}No tienes permisos suficientes para usar este comando.`);
    }

    if (!veh) {
        return player.outputChatBox(`!{red}[USO]: !{white}/irv [id]`);
    }

    try {
    const coord = await misc.query(`SELECT coord FROM vehicles WHERE id = ${veh}`);

    player.position = new mp.Vector3(coord.x, coord.y, coord.z);
    player.dimension = coord.dim;

    player.outputChatBox(`!{orange}Te has teletransportado con éxito al vehículo llave [${veh}]`);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(`[ERROR: /IRV]: ` + error);
    }
});
```

El problema que tengo es que sale el siguiente error, y no me teletransporta correctamente a la ubicación del vehículo.

**Error**

```
Invalid argument: expected Number[ERROR: /IRV]: Error: expected Number
```

Agradecería mucho una ayudita, ¡saludos!

Comment: ¿Has probado a depurar que el resultado de la consulta SQL es el que esperas? Haz un `console.log(coord)` tras la consulta y comprueba que sea una clase con los atributos `x`, `y`, `z` y `dim`. Todo apunta a que estás introduciendo un valor que no es un número a `mp.Vector()` (por ejemplo, un `undefined` si esos atributos no existen). Por cierto, no tiene muy buena pinta eso de concatenar variables a un código SQL...

Comment: Buenas Oscar.
Seguí tus pasos con lo del `console.log(coord)`, efectivamente es una clase con atributos x, y, z, y dim.

Comment: ¿Podrías copiar//pegar la salida exacta a la pregunta? Quiero comprobar también que coinciden los tipos y que los datos están dentro de una matriz (que sería lo lógico en el resultado de una consulta SQL).

Comment: Para ir adelantando, si lo que pienso es correcto, la manera de acceder a los datos del primer resultado de la consulta SQL sería `player.position = new mp.Vector3(coord[0].x, coord[0].y, coord[0].z);` (previa comprobación que al menos tengas un elemento en el resultado de la consulta).

Comment: A parte de lo que dice @OscarGarcia con lo que concuerdo totalmente, tienes que verificar que lo que le pasas a vector sea un número y no un string. Por lo que mostraste [en tu primera pregunta](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkITl.png) creo que no vas bien, porque `coord` tiene un montón de atributos pero no veo ninguno que sea  `.x`, `.y` o `.z`. En todo caso sería `.pos.x`, `pos.y` y `pos.z` y eso solo después de parsear ese string a objeto con JSON.parse, porque `pos` lo estás guardando como `string `en tu base de datos.

Comment: Gracias @JaimeMenéndez . Hasta que no comparta el contenido **exacto** del `console.log` que le indiqué lo único que podemos hacer es elucubrar. Pero sí, es posible que necesites hacer precisamente un `JSON.parse()` antes de poder acceder al contenido de los datos recibidos desde la base de datos.